# Sqoop export to SQL Server: schemas?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I would like to export data in HDFS to a SQL Server table in the schema `my_schema`.

I tried `--schema` like the import command:

```
sqoop export \
--libjars /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib/sqljdbc4.jar \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://MY-SERVER-DNS;database=my_db;" \
--schema "myschema" \
--table "my_table" \
--export-dir /path/to/my/hdfs/dir

ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --schema
```

And `--table "schema.table"`

```
sqoop export \
--libjars /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib/sqljdbc4.jar \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://MY-SERVER-DNS;database=my_db;" \
--table "my_schema.my_table" \
--export-dir /path/to/my/hdfs/dir

INFO manager.SqlManager: 
Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [my_schema.my_table] AS t WHERE 1=0 

ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
Invalid object name 'my_schema.my_table'.
```

Is there any way to do this with sqoop? Or another technology?

EDIT:

```
sqoop export \
--libjars /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib/sqljdbc4.jar \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://MY-SERVER-DNS;database=my_db;schema=my_schema;" \
--table "my_table" \
--export-dir /path/to/my/hdfs/dir

INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [my_table] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/07/25 10:46:21 ERROR manager.SqlManager: 
Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
Invalid object name 'my_table'.
```

This is not recognizing the schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

provide schema in connection string:

`jdbc:sqlserver://MY-SERVER-DNS;databaseName=my_db;schema=my_schema;`

so your export `sqoop` command should be:

```
sqoop export \
--libjars /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib/sqljdbc4.jar \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://MY-SERVER-DNS;databaseName=my_db;schema=my_schema;" \
--table "my_table" \
--export-dir /path/to/my/hdfs/dir
```

***ALSO:***

[Custom schemas are supported for both import and export job](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_schema_support) - from syntax in sqoop guide, `--schema` should be passed as `-- --schema`:

so your export `sqoop` command should be:

```
sqoop export \
--libjars /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib/sqljdbc4.jar \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://MY-SERVER-DNS;databaseName=my_db;" \
--export-dir /path/to/my/hdfs/dir
--table "my_table" \
-- --schema my_schema \
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by converting the Hive table from managed to External

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE new_table
AS
SELECT *
FROM old_table
```